# Highlight uiwebview text in tableview cell

Tags: javascript, iphone, search, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a uitableview that I have embedded a uiwebview in. The webview contains html text.   I'm searching and highlighting text in the webview with JavaScript. I have successfully made the search highlight the search text in the last tableview cell that was loaded, but how can I get it to highlight text in all the visible cells at the same time? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this?? Thanks.

Comment: Anyone been able to work this out??? If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated! I am stuck on this problem and can't seem to get it worked out... :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

then reload all webview using you highlight js code

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have tried this method and I still can't seem to get this working. Any other ideas would be great.